# Ubuntu 14.04 how to enable numlock for login screen

Tags: numlock

I'm a brand new Ubuntu user & I'm trying to enable numlock for the login screen in Ubuntu 14.04 I've tried all the answers I could find but none of them seem to work for me. All I got was a "low graphics mode" error.

Can anyone please provide clear step-by step Ubuntu for dummies type instructions? (Please remember I'm a complete noob at this) I've noticed a lot of solutions say things like just edit this file or that file, but I don't know how to do that stuff yet.

Thanks for any help given.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very nice and easy to follow guide - with commands listed.

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/turn-on-numlock-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: @Silverhand77 Excellent and glad to hear it. I'd done the same thing myself not long before.